# Why are my attempts to get a Braintree token suddenly not working when nothing changed?

Tags: java, braintree

I am using the following code, in java, to generate a token on my server and return it to my app:

```
BraintreeGateway gateway = new BraintreeGateway(
                  Environment.SANDBOX,
                  "my_merchant_id",
                  "my_public_key",
                  "my_private_key"
        );

        ResponseClass response = new ResponseClass(gateway.clientToken().generate());
        return response;
```

It has been working totally fine, up until about 10 minutes ago when i started getting a nil in my client. I run the above code on my server to see what is going on and the task is timing out in 15 seconds. Nothing changed, and I have verified my merchant id, public key, and private key (which were all working) still match what they say in the Braintree sandbox. Is this a braintree error? Is my braintree JAR suddenly out of date? Can't figure out where to start! thanks

Comment: Looks like either their server is down or there is a network problem.

Comment: I've tried googling to find if others are experiencing this or if Braintree has announced anything but couldn't find a thing. thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/)</sub>

This morning, some merchants may have experienced [slow API requests](https://status.braintreepayments.com/) in the Sandbox environment. This issue is now resolved.

I'd recommend contacting Braintree support at: support@braintreepayments.com if the issue persists.